# Move Object outside of Update() Function without teleporting

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

my goal of this function is to be able to call it by sending a message (click on a tile, tile sends a message to the object and the object moves to that tile's location).  I am in the process of creating the function that will be called when the message is sent.  The inner workings of it are seemingly simple.  I'm using:

```
Vector3 start = gameObject.transform.position;
    Vector3 finish = new Vector3(100, 1, 10);

        gameObject.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(start, finish, .1F);
```

I'm using hardcoded values for testing. If I remove this from my function and pop it into the Update() function, it works perfectly. But when i attempt to call the function:

```
void MoveToLocation()
{
    Vector3 start = gameObject.transform.position;
    Vector3 finish = new Vector3(100, 1, 10);
    for(int i = 0; i<10000; i++)
    {
        gameObject.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(start, finish, .1F);   
    }

}
```

(arbitrary step value for testing) using it inside of a for loop, the object does not move.  Is there some type of logic that I am missing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are not yielding/waiting at-all in the `for` loop. Check the second function in the duplicate question for how to move your object and wait over time.

Comment: Thank you very much. Sorry for the duplicate question!

Comment: That's fine. Not exactly the-same wording but the-same problem and solution. Happy coding!